# Bridging multiple WiFi networks to Starlink Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bridge

Preface: I'm a software engineer but have limited knowledge of IP networking.

I am tasked with taking an existing StarLink installation (round dish / 1st gen router) and making the internet connection available across a couple of disconnected buildings.

**Note**: It is not a requirement that we have one continuous network (i.e. it doesn't matter if a client connected to one router can "see" a client connected to another), *only* that all clients can access the internet.

I did the physical installation but am struggling with the network configuration.

[image]

(Excuse my poor network diagram)

- The Starlink router has a fixed IP of 192.168.1.1 and it has a DHCP range of 192.168.1.0/24 as I understand it. It broadcasts a wireless network.
- The Starlink router is hardwired to a WiFi access point (router 1) statically configured as 192.168.1.100. It broadcasts a wireless network (Router 1 WiFi).
- Router 1 is hardwired to a wifi p2p dish (WiFi P2P AP) statically configured as 192.168.1.101. It broadcasts a wireless network (Bridge WiFi).
- A second wifi p2p dish (wifi p2p client) is statically configured as 192.168.1.102 and joined to the bridge WiFi network.
- Router 2 is hardwired to the wifi p2p client dish and is statically configured as 192.168.1.103. It broadcasts a wireless network (Router 2 WiFi).

The routers downstream of the Starlink are configured to use it as the default gateway.

I fudged the DHCP settings on router 1 and router 2. They both run a DHCP server and are configured to give addresses between 192.168.1.150-199.

Fundamentally, the setup works: Clients connected to Starlink WiFi, router 1 WiFi and router 2 WiFi can all access the internet with good speed.

However, it seems sometimes unreliable and users report "periods of time where the connection was unreliable and an email might be unable to send or in which I get kicked off of online meetings repeatedly". That specific report came from a router 1 user; so I don't think it relates to the WiFi P2P bridge.

I recognize that my setup is flawed, particularly for DHCP. But how to do this *right*?

- It's not possible to change any setting on the StarLink router, and I'd rather not bypass it
- Can I put the downstream network on a different subnet (e.g. 192.168.2.0/24)?
- Can or should I put both router 1 and router 2 on different subnets?
- How should DHCP be configured, default gateway(s), etc?

**To reiterate what was state previously**: It is not a requirement that we have one continuous network, *only* that all wifi clients can access the internet. This isn't a mesh network; all WiFi interfaces are distinct SSIDs.

I hope that this is a simple question but I just don't have the knowledge to know what will work.

Comment: How many devices do you need to support? It sounds like the Starlink box is using 192.168.1.0/24 as its NAT private subnet, which gives you about 253 addresses on the LAN: Is that enough? What subset of that is its DHCP server configured to serve out? Sometimes a home gateway router like that will have its DHCP server only serve out addresses up to, say, .200, and leave addresses .201 - .254 for manual/reserved/static IP addresses. So is the Starlink router's DHCP pool—which is probably significantly smaller than its NAT private subnet—large enough to cover all your DHCP clients?

Comment: @Spiff Maybe 20 clients at most. The StarLink DHCP pool is big enough but totally non-configurable. I read some anecdotes that it only actually assigns a maximum of 128 IPs, starting at around .1.20. But this is not documented anywhere...

Comment: My idea is to put everything downstream of the StarLink on a different subnet (say, 192.168.2.0/24). I guess if router 1 uses the StarLink as it's default gateway that will work. But what about router 2? It's gateway will presumably be router 1... Will it still route to the internet? Should router 1 be the DHCP server for that whole subnet? I understand clients on the starlink network wouldn't "see" the downstream network, but I'd be fine with that....

Comment: That's something I was going to ask about. What's the current configuration of router 2 – is it connected to upstream via its "WAN" interface or via its "LAN" interface?

Comment: @u1686_grawity WAN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Starlink router is already acting as a NAT gateway and DHCP server for your network. You don't need any other devices to perform those roles, and in fact you shouldn't want them to, as multiple layers of NAT is a hassle that is rarely justified.

Make sure none of your routers are acting as NAT gateways or DHCP servers. Let the Starlink router be the only NAT gateway and DHCP server for the entire network. You want all the downstream "routers" to just be transparently bridging between Wi-Fi and all Ethernet ports. Some devices may call this "AP mode" or a kind of "bridge mode" (although in some contexts, "bridge mode" can refer to being a building-to-building wireless bridge, which isn't what I'm talking about; there's a frustrating lack of consistent terminology for these features across products and vendors). If your router has a mode where it can act as a plain IP-forwarding router without NAT, that still isn't what you want. You want traffic between Wi-Fi and any and all Ethernet ports to be transparently bridged.

If any of your routers don't let you disable NAT or DHCP service, there are workarounds. If you can't disable NAT, just remove the upstream cable from that router's WAN port and move it to one of that router's LAN ports. If you can't disable DHCP service, give the DHCP server a zero-length pool of IP addresses to serve out.

One nice thing about making all your routers just be bridges like this is that if you want, you could easily enable seamless roaming across your network. Just have them all publish the same network name (SSID) with the same wireless security type and password, and clients will automatically join or roam to the nearest AP.

Comment: Thanks! I can disable DHCP, and I believe NAT. Router 1 & 2 and the wifi bridge dishes need static IPs (otherwise, how can I configure them?). But I can't prevent them conflicting with the StarLink's DHCP pool. Is it a risk? Is DHCP smart enough to not assign a (non-reserved) IP address that already exists on the network (even though it didn't assign the IP itself)? My instinct says no...

Comment: @TheNextman: That's precisely why you disable DHCP – not the WAN DHCP _client_, but the LAN DHCP _server_ on the two secondary routers. If you physically reconnect routers as described (using the LAN ports), then you will have one large subnet across everything, and there should remain only one DHCP server within that subnet. (The issue isn't merely that the DHCP servers may assign duplicate IPs; don't forget that they also distribute "default gateway" information to hosts.)

Comment: I feel like Spiff's post is confusing "disabling NAT" with "disabling routing", though – on many routers, if you merely "disable NAT", it _literally_ disables only NAT but still keeps the LAN and WAN interfaces as two separately-routed networks, which is not enough to turn it into one giant subnet. (NAT and routing are separate things!) More often, I believe, the option to bridge the both sides together is actually called "bridge" mode.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I've updated my Answer to make it more clear that I'm talking about going straight from NAT to bridging, not stopping in between at plain routing.

Comment: @TheNextman I'm seeing some discussion online that Starlink routers might start their DHCP pool at .20, so if you can confirm that on your network (do you see anyone getting a DHCP lease below .20?) then you can keep the static IP addresses you're already using for your routers, since they all happen to be below .20. Also, Yes, DHCP Servers *and* Clients both work to avoid offering or accepting IP address leases for addresses that someone is already "squatting" on. But it's till best practice not to manually configure a device to use an IP address that's part of the DHCP pool.

Comment: I'd even more strongly recommend keeping the static and DHCP ranges separate – some DHCP servers will indeed probe an address before offering to lease it, and I think most DHCP clients will probe the offered address before accepting the lease, but... that only works if the "static" device is online at that particular time. But if it happens in the wrong order – e.g. static .25 device is offline; another device gets .25 leased via DHCP; static .25 device comes online – now you still have an address conflict. (Fortunately at least Windows will alert you when that happens.)

Comment: @Spiff I read the same but in my day job, I'd be nervous to build something on top of an undocumented behaviour like that...

Comment: Both answers here gave similar information and I took tips from both. Ultimately I followed the advice: (1) connect downstream routers via a LAN interface, not WAN (2) ensure they are operating in "access point" mode (3) disable DHCP on downstream routers (4) assign routers and bridges a static IP below .20 to try and keep them out of StarLink's DHCP pool. So far everything working well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Routers *separate* IP subnets. Two interfaces of a router should never be configured for the same IP network – even if you can get away with it sometimes, it will only end in headaches if you do so.

- This works at the level of 'whole networks', not individual addresses. So it's not enough to "fudge DHCP" so the two sides merely use different parts of the same 192.168.1.0/24 (e.g. 100-149 vs 150-199), because routers don't really track individual IP addresses like that – they primarily deal with "whole subnet" routes, so you still have two of the same /24 and that's still bad.

  (Keep in mind that a typical "wireless router" is half a router and half a bridge, depending on how it's connected. The 'router proper' sits between LAN/WiFi and WAN, while all of the LAN ports (including Wi-Fi) are bridged together and bypass the router.)

  So if Router1 is connected to its upstream through the WAN port, and the WAN port is configured with 192.168.1.x/24, then you cannot<sup>1</sup> use the same 192.168.1.x/24 on its LAN interface (even if x differs), because then you have two *separate* networks using the same subnet number.

  (As mentioned above, it's because the router works at whole-network level, so has two duplicate routes for the same 192.168.1.0/24 via both interfaces, and it doesn't track which individual IPs are behind which interface.)

So with the routers connected the way they are now (via WAN ports as you mentioned), it means you **physically have three networks** at the moment: the "Starlink LAN"; the "Router1 LAN"; and the "Router2 LAN". That tells you that they should have separate IP subnets (.2.0/24, .3.0/24, etc).

---

Assigning separate IP subnets is the most straightforward way to fix things, but it's not really *nice* because all three routers also have NAT enabled, and NAT in the middle of a network is ugly. (Although, according to your requirements it's not *really* a problem in itself, but it's still ugly in concept.)

There are two other ways to connect the networks (the decision can be made separately for R1 and R2):

0. You could keep them connected as-is, with routing and NAT.
1. You could disable only the NAT, while still having separately routed subnets.
2. You could bypass routing entirely, bridging both sides of a router into one subnet.

Option 1 has the downside that you need to configure "downstream" routes in every upstream router, and the Starlink router probably won't let you do that at all, so while it's the usual option for enterprise networks, it's probably not an option for you.

Spiff suggests option 2 across both R1 and R2 – bridging everything into a single giant subnet. Some wireless routers have a dedicated option for that (e.g. "bridge mode", but I don't think I've ever seen a router that calls it "NAT"), while others don't have a specific option at all – but, as mentioned before, *pretty much all of them* already have all LAN ports bridged, so there's an easy workaround.

When doing the bridging, you will have only one actual 'router' (R1 and R2 will not be doing any routing anymore) and therefore only one subnet (the "Starlink LAN" subnet reaching through all bridges). There should be only one DHCP server across the entire subnet.

An advantage of the bridge approach is that you get single-SSID Wi-Fi roaming *for free* – you don't actually need "mesh" for that; you merely need the participating Wi-Fi access points to be bridged to each other.

This may have the slight downside that your Starlink router may run out of available DHCP leases, because it needs to lease addresses to devices in *both* buildings. It would be good to know whether the Starlink router at least allows you to use a /22 subnet or similar (i.e. larger than /24).

Comment: Thank you. For option 1 and downstream routes, that would only be necessary for the downstream network to be visible from the starling side, right? So it would work given my disclaimer in the OP

Comment: Option 2 does sound better; but won't my routers management interface now be assigned by DHCP? I believe the routers I have can be configured in bridge mode FYI.

Comment: "won't my routers management interface now be assigned by DHCP" – that's optional, you can still use static IP addresses for routers (although DHCP is not inherently a problem either).

Comment: "For option 1 and downstream routes, that would only be necessary for the downstream network to be visible from the starling side" – No; "technically yes" but you have to remember that *replies* from Internet also have to travel the same way as fresh requests. So without routes downstream, those devices won't be able to establish any connections. (In other words, option 0 works *because of* NAT, which "hides" the downstream network from the upstream router.)

Comment: Both answers here gave similar information and I took tips from both. Ultimately I followed the advice: (1) connect downstream routers via a LAN interface, not WAN (2) ensure they are operating in "access point" mode (3) disable DHCP on downstream routers (4) assign routers and bridges a static IP below .20 to try and keep them out of StarLink's DHCP pool. So far everything working well. Thank you!